# What is the meaning of an "attached" object in JDO/DataNucleus?

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

The DataNucleus docs talk a lot about detached objects and what it means to be detached, but, for new users, they kind of skip over the simplistic: What does it mean to be attached?

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_1_1/jdo/attach_detach.html

If I perform:

```
MyPersistableObj p = pm.makePersistent(myNewPersistableObj);
```

If I understand correctly, I'm getting back a copy of the object that was just posted to the database, but how that is special is a bit fuzzy.

- If I make a change to one of the fields of that object, does that automatically cause an update to the database? The docs seem to hint at this, but don't call it out in particular.
- Do I need to "detach" it to ensure this doesn't happen?
- How does this (JDO's attach/detach functionality) differ from SQL, where I'm used to *simple-to-understand, atomic*, inserts, queries, updates, and deletes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDO object lifecycle is well defined in http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_2_2/jdo/object_lifecycle.html
"attached" is simply 'managed by the PersistenceManager' so a state like "Persistent Clean"

Comment: Ah thanks, I had skimmed over that document but didn't really make the connection with attach/detach. Sometimes reading the documentation is like learning something from the bottom up, there's lots of information but it doesn't always connect until you get to the top of the tree. The attach/detach page should probably call out object lifecycle as pre-requisite to understanding the attach/detach concept. Thanks for the help!